# How can I pull and concactenate a Wikipedia table with individual article data

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

I'm looking to pull together a full list of the current FTSE 100 constituents with the addition of a column highlighting when the company was founded.

Each wiki info box for the individual companies within a table contains the founder date. I'm struggling to work out the function in sparql utilising dbpedia to take the existing ftse 100 table.

Comment: Look at some example resource on DBpedia and see whether there is some information that indicates FTSE 100: http://dbpedia.org/resource/3i  http://dbpedia.org/resource/Antofagasta_PLC etc  Then write the SPARQL query given that you found the specific information. I can't see such information as this isn't contained in the infobox and that's what the data in DBpedia is mostly based on.

Comment: Alternatively, look at the resource for FTSE 100: http://dbpedia.org/page/FTSE_100_Index Again, if you find something that relates to the companies, write the SPARQL query.

Comment: Maybe you have some more luck with a Wikipedia category, but I can only see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Companies_listed_on_the_London_Stock_Exchange but not something like indexed in the top 100

Comment: Don't forget, this data would be very dynamic and DBpedia is based on Wikipedia dumps, thus, never in sync with the current Wikipedia data.

Comment: The closest I got `select * {
?company dct:subject <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:Companies_listed_on_the_London_Stock_Exchange> ;
<http://dbpedia.org/ontology/foundingYear> ?fYear
}` but without the filter for FTSE 100 - sorry

Comment: It's worth noting that more current (they try to be up to the hour if not the minute) Wikipedia data can be found in the "live" DBpedia endpoints — <http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql/> and <http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql/>.

Comment: You might try getting your FTSE100 member list from elsewhere, and using that as the base for a `SERVICE` query against DBpedia by which to get the dates of foundation. You might also suggest to your favorite market info source(s) that they add DBpedia links to their pages...